# Pandas dataframe from unique numpy elements

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I want to construct a pandas dataframe where columns have elements from specified arrays with unique elements only. **I want to find the most efficient pythonic way of doing this.**

For example, I have the following numpy arrays as input:

```
a = np.array(["a1"])
b = np.array(["b1", "b2"])
c = np.array(["c1", "c2", "c3"])
```

**Below is how I want my Pandas dataframe to be like**

```
    a   b   c
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a1  b1  c2
2  a1  b1  c3
3  a1  b2  c1
4  a1  b2  c2
5  a1  b2  c3
```

Below is the code that I am using:

```
import pandas as pd

hashmap = {"a":[], "b":[], "c":[]}

for a_elem in a:
    for b_elem in b:
        for c_elem in c:
            hashmap["a"] += [a_elem]
            hashmap["b"] += [b_elem]
            hashmap["c"] += [c_elem]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hashmap)
```

How can I make this code more efficient?

Comment: Related: [cartesian product in pandas](/q/13269890/4518341) and [How to get the Cartesian product of multiple lists](/q/533905/4518341)

Comment: Also possibly related: [Using NumPy to build an array of all combinations of two arrays](/q/1208118/4518341) and [Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](/q/11144513/4518341). (I've only glanced at them and I'm not a NumPy expert.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(product(a, b, c), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a1  b1  c2
2  a1  b1  c3
3  a1  b2  c1
4  a1  b2  c2
5  a1  b2  c3
```

Alternative with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, b, c], names=['a', 'b', 'c']
                                ).to_frame(index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.DataFrame([(x, y, z) for x in a for y in b for z in c], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

---

Or using [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(a, b, c, indexing='ij')
pd.DataFrame({'a': x.ravel(), 'b': y.ravel(), 'c': z.ravel()})
```

---

Or yet using a more general approach:

```
arrs = [a, b, c]
mesh = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*arrs, indexing='ij'), -1).reshape(-1, len(arrs))
pd.DataFrame(mesh, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

---

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a1  b1  c2
2  a1  b1  c3
3  a1  b2  c1
4  a1  b2  c2
5  a1  b2  c3
```